# Application failed codesign verification - again?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Ok. I know. This has been covered 100^1000 times here and everywhere, but I have been trying to create my .ipa for submission for the past week (not kidding, thats how much I spent working on just this) and I keep getting this warning. BTW - not sure it makes a difference, but thats an iPad app.

I am getting this warning:

> warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
>   Executable=/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JudgeIt-ebfrsivdbrxukqhbupfnzzqgoftd/ArchiveIntermediates/JudgeIt/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/JudgeIt.app/JudgeIt
>   codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
>   Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier, 6366MSW2TK.com.JudgeIt.JudgeIt
>   Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers, {type = mutable-small, count = 1, values = (
>       0 : {contents = "6366MSW2TK.com.JudgeIt.JudgeIt"}
>   )}
>   AssertMacros: filter_entitlements(entitlements_whitelist, entitlements_requested, allowable_entitlements),  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 932
>    - (null)

I tried:

- Delete all the certificates and keys and start all over again
- Unistall Xcode
- Restarting my computer
- Deleting build library
- Cleaning project

Also attaching a screenshot of the Code Signing setting of my project - looks ok to me.

[image]

UPDATES: 
 - I am using Xcode 4.2
 - All certificates on Keychain are valid and I have one of each (developer, distribution, AWDR)

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: If not done already, upgrade to Xcode 4.2.1 on Lion. All Xcode 4 versions on Snow Leopard I have used in the past have issues with code signing.

Comment: Additional things to check, first in "Keychain Access.app": Is the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" valid?  Is your distribution certificate valid? Is there only one? (if you got old ones still around, delete them) Then in Xcode Organizer: in both "Developer Profile" and "Provisioning Profiles", make sure that every profile exists exactly once, delete all old profiles (I've seen Xcode pick up old ones while there were new/valid ones available).

Comment: Will try that, though it doesnt look from the release notes that they fixed anything related to this. Will update my post.

Comment: Dark Dust - all those have things are in place. It's not that I guess. thanks though.

Comment: If not done already, be sure to also ask for help on the Apple Developer Forum. Often Apple employees frequent the forum and might help you out. If everything else fails, remember that with the $99 you paid you're entitled to filing two [Technical Support Incidents](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) per year. It's targeted towards helping you with code issues, but I think this issue qualifies as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound totally stupid, but that was the failure message when I wanted to validate my archive yesterday while submitting an app. I had used a "+" sign in the bundle name, and that was the problem source!! Renaming the required fields, I didn't get the code sign error anymore!!